# How to fix the huge indent

Tags: plugin-vim-latex

[image]

I am using nvim to edit tex files. I don't know what happened. All of a sudden, tens of blank lines emerged before each line of codes. I think maybe I screwed it up by doing something wrong unconsciously. Does anyone can shed light on some ways to fix it? thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! From the line-numbering, it appears you have `'wrap'` turned on, and that there's really a large number of whitespace characters (not blank lines) at the beginning of the line. You could try `==` or `<<.....` to unindent if the indentation settings are still correct.

Answer (score 2):

My suspicion is that you have done some "repeat" command by typing a number in normal mode before applying a command, probably block-wise.

Consider this:

[image]

If you block-select the first column, and then insert a space (or indent) 100 times, command `Ctrl-V G 100 I <space> <esc>`, you have:

[image]

it seems you have inserted line, but it is just space.... use `:set nowrap" to remove the soft wrapping of lines, and enlarge the window:

[image]

Now you could use a regex, but you can also use normal blockwise: `Ctrl-V`, select the blank space:

[image]

and then `d` will remove it.